# How to automatically change variable names given a new input file name

Tags: matlab

I am importing data from a `.mat` file and then extracting certain signals from it and I call this data, `data`. `data` is a 1x1 struct with 1 field, `FT_est_X`, where X is the the particular run that I collected the samples from. Here is the code snippet of how I do that.

```
data = load('site_data_all_2.mat');
t  = data.FT_est_2.time;
% estimated data
Fx = data.FT_est_2.signals(1).values;
Fy = data.FT_est_2.signals(2).values;
Fz = data.FT_est_2.signals(3).values;
Mx = data.FT_est_2.signals(4).values;
My = data.FT_est_2.signals(5).values;
Mz = data.FT_est_2.signals(6).values;
```

So, you can see that this data was collected from run 2. Now, let's say I want to load in a file named `site_data_all_3.mat` (run 3), what happens is that all the data below `%estimated data` changes its name--everything stays the same, except the `2` becomes a `3` (e.g. Fx would be `Fx = data.FT_est_3.signals(1).values;`. Currently, I have to manually enter in the `3` for each variable; can anyone tell me how I can only change the file name and it will automatically change the variable names for me? Essentially, I just want it to be `Fx = data.name_of_struct_field.signals(1).values`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the string some programmatic way (maybe with an iteration variable), but here's the simple answer of defining the fieldname as a string and simply using it. At the next iteration, update the fieldname variable and repeat.

```
fieldname = 'FT_est_2';
Fx = data.(fieldname).signals(1).values;
```